# How to match a function with chai.should

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

Let say that a function should return the following

```
{ key: 'bar',
  cb: () => {},
  ...
}
```

The question is now how I can validate this in a unit test. If I do for example

```
getFunc().should.eql({key: 'bar', cb: () => {}, ...});
```

it always fails because the `cb` value is a different function
Does `Chai.should` have an equivalent of `jasmine.any(Function)` ? or how is this done with chai.should ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dug around in the chai docs and `instanceOf` seems to be the best candidate for an equivalent of `jasmine.any(Function)`.

```
var result = getFunc();
result.cb.should.be.instanceOf(Function);
result.should.contain.all.keys(['key']);
```